# How to loop a 2D array and store objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im trying to store objects into the array. I tried using the 2D array loop and im not getting the right results that i want. Can i know what is wrong and how do i fix it? Its printing 15 times instead of 5 times just like how i want the `output` stated below.

**Input:**

```
var places = ['Place A', 'Place B', 'Place C', 'Place D', 'Place E'];
var data = [];
var results = [
  [ '1.3784294469999998', '103.9424764', '519498' ],
  [ '1.325617641', '103.67841059999999', '629117' ],
  [ '1.3835802030000002', '103.7707748', '670445' ],
  [ '1.322595392', '103.8136987', '258748' ],
  [ '1.3061957990000002', '103.828509', '238884' ]
]
```

**Output I want:**

```
[
  [ places: 'Place A', lat: '1.3784294469999998', lon: '103.9424764', zip: '519498' ],
  [ places: 'Place B', lat: '1.325617641', lon: '103.67841059999999', zip: '629117' ],
  [ places: 'Place C',lat: '1.3835802030000002', lon: '103.7707748', zip: '670445' ],
  [ places: 'Place D',lat: '1.322595392', lon: '103.8136987', '258748' ],
  [ places: 'Place E',lat: '1.3061957990000002', lon: '103.828509', zip: '238884' ]
]
```

**Code:**

```
  for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < results[i].length; j++) {
      data.push({ places: places[i], lat: results[i][j], lon: results[i][j], zip: [i][j]});
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a single loop, not a nested loop:

```js
var places = ['Place A', 'Place B', 'Place C', 'Place D', 'Place E'];
var data = [];
var results = [
  [ '1.3784294469999998', '103.9424764', '519498' ],
  [ '1.325617641', '103.67841059999999', '629117' ],
  [ '1.3835802030000002', '103.7707748', '670445' ],
  [ '1.322595392', '103.8136987', '258748' ],
  [ '1.3061957990000002', '103.828509', '238884' ]
];
for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
  data.push({ places: places[i], lat: results[i][0], lon: results[i][1], zip: results[i][2]});
}
console.log(data);
```

Or, perhaps more readably with `.map` and destructuring:

```js
var places = ['Place A', 'Place B', 'Place C', 'Place D', 'Place E'];
var results = [
  [ '1.3784294469999998', '103.9424764', '519498' ],
  [ '1.325617641', '103.67841059999999', '629117' ],
  [ '1.3835802030000002', '103.7707748', '670445' ],
  [ '1.322595392', '103.8136987', '258748' ],
  [ '1.3061957990000002', '103.828509', '238884' ]
];
const data = results.map(
  ([lat, lon, zip], i) => ({ places: places[i], lat, lon, zip })
);
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

#### What is happening in your code

Currently with your for loop for every element in `places` it will go over every nested element in `results`. This is how you get your 15 entries (5 placed times 3 results)

#### Solution:

```
for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    data.push({ places: places[i], lat: results[i][0], lon: results[i][1], zip: [i][2]});
}
```

This will loop over all your `places` and add the `results` in. It is almost what you had, but without the nested for loop and `j` replaced for the index of `lat`, `lon` and `zip` respectively.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! I think this is the clearest and very simple to understand. I was thinking too hard when its actually quite simple. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in a function and return the results like so:

```
function combine() {
  let data = []
  for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < results[i].length; j++) {
      data.push({ places: places[i], lat: results[i][j], lon: results[i][j], zip: [i][j]});
    }
  }
  return data
}
```